# Updating my ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel that is something very similar to this:

```
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionAnswer> QuestionAnswers { get; set; }
```

I populate the lists in the Controller and I pass the ViewModel to the View.  Everything works great.  However, my View is updatable (Read/Write).

I'm wondering is this the best way to accomplish this?  What is the best way to update my QuestionAnswers?

Do I loop the form collection or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Just curious, every Question has a Answer. Why not put the Awnsear inside the question?

Comment: @Fals - Like most responses...  It isn't my table design..  I'm trying to get it restructured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate your razor view like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyPostAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.QuestionAnswers.Count; i++)
        {           
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QuestionAnswers[i].Answer)
        }
}
```

Then in your MyPostAction catch the submitted results

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPostAction(List<QuestionAnswer> QuestionAnswers)
{
     foreach (var questionAnswer in QuestionAnswers)
     {
           // Do your DB update here
     }

     return View();
}
```

If you need to update both questions and questionAnswer lists in the same post action you can pass in two list collections as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of best practices I would say you have a good approach but in terms of architecture, you would be better off putting the answer collection within the question itself.